# How to hold a point to point wired connection up

Tags: networking, 18.04, ifconfig

I am trying to transfer files between two computers over a point to point gigabit Ethernet connection.

I run the following command to bring up the interface:

```
ifconfig eno1 192.168.100.1 up
```

On the other connected machine I set the IP address to 192.168.100.2.  I can then run an rsync command and start transferring files.  But after a few seconds I get an error notification pop up:

```
Connection failed
"Activation of network connection failed"
```

And then suddenly the route goes away and the interface goes down and my rsync fails.

How can I keep the connection up?

Comment: which ubuntu version, desktop/server ?

Comment: @cmak.fr 18.04 (desktop)